# Problems loading geojson from web in mapbox

Tags: cors, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to load a geojson from this [link](http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/geoserver/geoportal/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=geoportal%3Alote_cidadao&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application%2Fjson) in mapbox using mapbox-gl and react. At first I started getting a CORS error, which I fixed (maybe?) with this chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Now I no longer get any errors, but also the geojson data is not displayed on my map. Any ideas what this could be or how fix this? Thank you! This is my code, it uses react:

```
const geosampa : any = {
    id: 'geosampa',
    type: 'geojson',
    data: 'http://wfs.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/geoserver/geoportal/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=geoportal%3Alote_cidadao&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',
};

const Fills : FillLayer = {
    'id': 'fills',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'geosampa',
    'paint': {
        'fill-outline-color': '#484896',
        'fill-color': '#fff',
        'fill-opacity': 0.4
        },
 };
```

And then later I am calling it as:

```
<Source {...geosampa}>
    <Layer {...Fills} />
</Source>
```